# Changing milliseconds from 3 digits to 2 digits

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am having trouble making a stopwatch that only uses 2 digits for the milliseconds part. I have the full JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jauc5yLd/). The function I could use some help with is the `formatter()` method.

Right now, the method looks like this:

```
formatter(timeInMilliseconds) {
  const padZero = (time) => {
    while (time.length < 2) { 
      time = '0' + time; 
    } 
    return time;
  }

  let time = new Date(timeInMilliseconds);
  let minutes = padZero(time.getMinutes().toString());
  let seconds = padZero(time.getSeconds().toString());
  let milliseconds = padZero((time.getMilliseconds() / 10).toFixed(0));

  let output = `${minutes} : ${seconds} . ${milliseconds}`;
  console.log(output);
  return output;
}
```

For the most part, it works. The problem though is very visible if you look at the console of my JSFiddle while the timer is running. For example, if the stopwatch is currently at something like `00 : 15 . 99`, it will become `00 : 15 . 100` at the next tick instead of `00 : 16 . 00`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would appreciate it if I was given suggestions on improving my question instead of given downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toFixed` rounds rather than truncating, so 995 milliseconds and up will become 99.5 and be formatted to `100` by `toFixed`. You can convert it to an integer and then to a string instead to truncate it:

```
let milliseconds = padZero('' + (time.getMilliseconds() / 10 | 0));
```

It might also be a nice simplification to make `padZero` accept a number rather than a string:

```
function padZero(time) {
    return time < 10 ? '0' + time : '' + time;
}

let time = new Date(timeInMilliseconds);
let minutes = padZero(time.getMinutes());
let seconds = padZero(time.getSeconds());
let milliseconds = padZero(time.getMilliseconds() / 10 | 0);

let output = `${minutes} : ${seconds} . ${milliseconds}`;
```

Finally, if `timeInMilliseconds` isn’t a timestamp in milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC and is instead a duration, it’s inappropriate to convert it to a `Date`. Just do some math:

```
const minutes = padZero(timeInMilliseconds / 60000 | 0);
const seconds = padZero((timeInMilliseconds / 1000 | 0) % 60);
const centiseconds = padZero((timeInMilliseconds / 10 | 0) % 100);
```

Comment: Upvoted, thanks. I'm going to go with Joshua's answer since there is less conversion involved, but I appreciate you taking the time to answer!

Comment: @meh_programmer: My pleasure! I’m hoping “less conversion” is about readability and not performance, by the way, because it’s readability that’s more important. (That and `| 0` is faster than `Math.floor` and `toFixed` is still an even slower conversion to string.)

Comment: Yeah it was about readability, but I think I'm going to be going with your design after all. I really appreciate you being so thorough with this and showing a better/more accurate way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `.toFixed()` rounds instead of truncating.

```
(99.4).toFixed(0) == '99'
(99.5).toFixed(0) == '100'
```

All you need to do is replace

```
(time.getMilliseconds() / 10).toFixed(0)
```

with

```
Math.floor(time.getMilliseconds() / 10).toFixed(0)
```

and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring()

```
let milliseconds = padZero((time.getMilliseconds() / 10).toFixed(0)).substr(0, 2);
```

Comment: That won't fix the minutes part.

Comment: I'm kind of looking for a different way to do it. I know that I could just take a substring of the milliseconds and manually update the minutes part, but that seems very hacky to me.

Comment: See one of the other answers instead.